# Is autogenerated app.config in class library necessary for Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget, app-config

I have installed [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) via [NuGet Package Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManager) in Visual Studio. In every project I installed this package, an `app.config` file appeared which looks exactly like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DatabaseContext" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=Namespace.ContextName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I am wondering if this information is only necessary in the **startup project** (and the unit test project). Can I delete the `app.config` files from the class library projects, which just uses the `DbContext`?

Comment: Have you tried deleting it and seeing what happens?

Comment: I was not able to do it yet. As soon I tried it I will post my result, when nobody provided an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can delete them from your projects and just leave it at the startup project. But your main project should have a referente to the EF package as well. So when you debug or build a release, your satellite dll will actually use your startup project's app.config file.

Remeber ... when you upgrade EF or another package via nuget, it will add the app.config files all again.